# Need to manipulate returned JSON Object and extract a portion to a List

Tags: java, json, api

I'm consuming an external API, for which a JSON Object is returned. Contained in that Object response is an array that I need to extract and set to a List of a particular entity type. Java, however, is not a language that I'm very familiar with, so I'm having problems attempting to figure this out.

I've created a type of wrapper class to work with this in the setter.

The best I've come up with that compiles is below, but produces an error that I can't figure out.

```
public void setFlights(Object responseBody) {
    String responseString = responseBody.toString();
    JSONObject responseJSONObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
    JSONArray responseJSONArray = responseJSONObject.getJSONArray("flights");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type flightType = new TypeToken<List<Flight>>() {}.getType();
    this.flights = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(responseJSONArray), flightType);
}
```

As you can see, I'm kind of throwing it at the wall to see if it will stick. I'm trying to use Gson to get around some of the Type issues I've come across.

The error produced when executing is:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ':' after a key at 7 [character 8 line 1]
```

Response String is as follows:
[Response String Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPRRr.jpg)

If that's difficult to deal with, here's the response in text:

```
INFO: {"FlightInfoResult":{"next_offset":-1,"flights":[{"ident":"N1RJ","aircrafttype":"HDJT","filed_ete":"01:25:00","filed_time":1593038253,"filed_departuretime":1593037500,"filed_airspeed_kts":400,"filed_airspeed_mach":"","filed_altitude":360,"route":"WEAZL4 CLAWD","actualdeparturetime":1593038285,"estimatedarrivaltime":1593043320,"actualarrivaltime":1593043320,"diverted":"","origin":"KJQF","destination":"KJXN","originName":"Concord-Padgett Rgnl","originCity":"Concord, NC","destinationName":"Jackson County","destinationCity":"Jackson, MI"},{"ident":"N1RJ","aircrafttype":"HDJT","filed_ete":"01:24:00","filed_time":1593000320,"filed_departuretime":1592998200,"filed_airspeed_kts":400,"filed_airspeed_mach":"","filed_altitude":350,"route":"PEGTE","actualdeparturetime":1593000420,"estimatedarrivaltime":1593005149,"actualarrivaltime":1593005149,"diverted":"","origin":"KJXN","destination":"KJQF","originName":"Jackson County","originCity":"Jackson, MI","destinationName":"Concord-Padgett Rgnl","destinationCity":"Concord, NC"},{"ident":"N1RJ","aircrafttype":"HDJT","filed_ete":"01:29:00","filed_time":1592518049,"filed_departuretime":1592513400,"filed_airspeed_kts":317,"filed_airspeed_mach":"","filed_altitude":360,"route":"WEAZL4 CLAWD","actualdeparturetime":1592517936,"estimatedarrivaltime":1592523120,"actualarrivaltime":1592523120,"diverted":"","origin":"KJQF","destination":"KJXN","originName":"Concord-Padgett Rgnl","originCity":"Concord, NC","destinationName":"Jackson County","destinationCity":"Jackson, MI"},{"ident":"N1RJ","aircrafttype":"HDJT","filed_ete":"01:24:00","filed_time":1592481020,"filed_departuretime":1592479800,"filed_airspeed_kts":319,"filed_airspeed_mach":"","filed_altitude":350,"route":"PEGTE","actualdeparturetime":1592481126,"estimatedarrivaltime":1592486100,"actualarrivaltime":1592486100,"diverted":"","origin":"KJXN","destination":"KJQF","originName":"Jackson County","originCity":"Jackson, MI","destinationName":"Concord-Padgett Rgnl","destinationCity":"Concord, NC"}]}}
```

There very well may be a much more simple way of accomplishing what I need. Any example help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just added. Sorry about that.

Comment: `flights` is not a property of your JSON object, it's a property of `FlightInfoResult` property. You need something like `json.getJSONObject("FlightInfoResult").getJSONArray("flights")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson string to object mapper class directly as like below,

```
package com.sample.programs;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
public class FlightInfoResultMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "{\"FlightInfoResult\":{\"next_offset\":-1,\"flights\":[{\"ident\":\"N1RJ\",\"aircrafttype\":\"HDJT\",\"filed_ete\":\"01:25:00\",\"filed_time\":1593038253,\"filed_departuretime\":1593037500,\"filed_airspeed_kts\":400,\"filed_airspeed_mach\":\"\",\"filed_altitude\":360,\"route\":\"WEAZL4 CLAWD\",\"actualdeparturetime\":1593038285,\"estimatedarrivaltime\":1593043320,\"actualarrivaltime\":1593043320,\"diverted\":\"\",\"origin\":\"KJQF\",\"destination\":\"KJXN\",\"originName\":\"Concord-Padgett Rgnl\",\"originCity\":\"Concord, NC\",\"destinationName\":\"Jackson County\",\"destinationCity\":\"Jackson, MI\"},{\"ident\":\"N1RJ\",\"aircrafttype\":\"HDJT\",\"filed_ete\":\"01:24:00\",\"filed_time\":1593000320,\"filed_departuretime\":1592998200,\"filed_airspeed_kts\":400,\"filed_airspeed_mach\":\"\",\"filed_altitude\":350,\"route\":\"PEGTE\",\"actualdeparturetime\":1593000420,\"estimatedarrivaltime\":1593005149,\"actualarrivaltime\":1593005149,\"diverted\":\"\",\"origin\":\"KJXN\",\"destination\":\"KJQF\",\"originName\":\"Jackson County\",\"originCity\":\"Jackson, MI\",\"destinationName\":\"Concord-Padgett Rgnl\",\"destinationCity\":\"Concord, NC\"},{\"ident\":\"N1RJ\",\"aircrafttype\":\"HDJT\",\"filed_ete\":\"01:29:00\",\"filed_time\":1592518049,\"filed_departuretime\":1592513400,\"filed_airspeed_kts\":317,\"filed_airspeed_mach\":\"\",\"filed_altitude\":360,\"route\":\"WEAZL4 CLAWD\",\"actualdeparturetime\":1592517936,\"estimatedarrivaltime\":1592523120,\"actualarrivaltime\":1592523120,\"diverted\":\"\",\"origin\":\"KJQF\",\"destination\":\"KJXN\",\"originName\":\"Concord-Padgett Rgnl\",\"originCity\":\"Concord, NC\",\"destinationName\":\"Jackson County\",\"destinationCity\":\"Jackson, MI\"},{\"ident\":\"N1RJ\",\"aircrafttype\":\"HDJT\",\"filed_ete\":\"01:24:00\",\"filed_time\":1592481020,\"filed_departuretime\":1592479800,\"filed_airspeed_kts\":319,\"filed_airspeed_mach\":\"\",\"filed_altitude\":350,\"route\":\"PEGTE\",\"actualdeparturetime\":1592481126,\"estimatedarrivaltime\":1592486100,\"actualarrivaltime\":1592486100,\"diverted\":\"\",\"origin\":\"KJXN\",\"destination\":\"KJQF\",\"originName\":\"Jackson County\",\"originCity\":\"Jackson, MI\",\"destinationName\":\"Concord-Padgett Rgnl\",\"destinationCity\":\"Concord, NC\"}]}}";
    System.out.println("input - " + input);
    //Create Gson object
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    FlightInfoResultObject responseObject = gson.fromJson(input, FlightInfoResultObject.class);
    // parsing response to java pojo
    List<Flights> listOfFlights = responseObject.getFlightInfoResult().getFlights();
    for (Flights flight : listOfFlights) {
        System.out.println("flight - " + flight.getIdent());
    }
  }

}
```

Object Mapping class: Inside Flights.class you can add all the variable which you have in json response.

```
 class FlightInfoResultObject {

  FlightInfoResult FlightInfoResult;
  @Getter
  @Setter
 }

class FlightInfoResult {

   Integer next_offset;
   List<Flights> flights;
   @Getter
   @Setter
}

class Flights {
  String ident;
  String aircrafttype;
  @Getter
  @Setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to retrieve the inner JSON element directly using gson.
You have to get `FlightInfoResult` then `flights` accordingly. This should work:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject jsonObject = com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(responseString).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray flightArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("FlightInfoResult").getAsJsonArray("flights");
    Type flightType = new TypeToken<List<Flight>>() {}.getType();
    List<Flight> flights = gson.fromJson(flightArray, flightType);
```

Anyway, make sure the name of all properties inside class Flight matches Json elements name, to avoid mapping errors.
Since you didn't post your Flight class definition and gson naming rule, but the Flight class should be like:

```
public class Flight {

  private String ident;
  private String aircrafttype;
  private String filed_ete;
  private float filed_time;
  private float filed_departuretime;
  private float filed_airspeed_kts;
  private String filed_airspeed_mach;
  private float filed_altitude;
  private String route;
  private float actualdeparturetime;
  private float estimatedarrivaltime;
  private float actualarrivaltime;
  private String diverted;
  private String origin;
  private String destination;
  private String originName;
  private String originCity;
  private String destinationName;
  private String destinationCity;

// getters setters
```

Comment: This got me close! The gson manipulation worked without creating errors, and my Flight entity is already mapped with the attributes of the "flights" section. I'm still getting errors from my service bean, so I'm still working with it. I'll let you know. Thank you for this potential solution!